# What prevents me from just editing the /etc/shadow file in unencrypted systems?

Tags: linux, security, password, shadow

Real dumb question, but suppose a computer with Linux does not have an encrypted hard drive. If I generated a hash with *"openssl passwd"*, couldn't I just run a live version of Ubuntu and add my hash to the /etc/shadow file? Or is /etc/shadow encrypted even if the hard drive isn't?

Comment: Note that encryption is not the same as authentication. Authenticating some data as correct requires adding information to it, the authentication tag. And as far as I understand, that's something disk encryption doesn't usually do, since it would create some buffering issues. Depending on the encryption used, an attacker may be limited to just turning individual encryption blocks into garbage (but without the encryption layer being any wiser), but could also be able to flip individual bits, which is huge if they can guess what the plaintext originally was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What prevents me from just editing the /etc/shadow file in unencrypted systems?

Nothing, there is no specific protection for `/etc/shadow`. Some systems might have tampering detection, so the system administrator would know that `/etc/shadow` was changed (unless you also overrode the tampering detection, typically by updating it so it considered your modified `/etc/shadow` as correct), but nothing stops you from editing files in an unencrypted file system.

Encrypting the drive (or the partition holding `/etc/shadow`) is sufficient to prevent such attacks, but not to prevent more sophisticated attacks. Full protection against attacks involving physical access is still not quite there, although Secure Boot and TPM measurements do make successful attacks much harder.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is stupid, but doesn't that make security kind of a moot point, if anyone can just as easily add their own passwords to the root? Would encrypting the hard drive be sufficient to prevent this kind of attack?

Comment: @VictorChavauty It is not at all stupid; it highlights an aspect of computer security that is often (well, nowadays maybe not so much anymore) overlooked: once an attacker gains _physical access_ to the hardware, you're in deep trouble. That is the reason behind hardware-level encryption such as Bitlocker (TM) etc. If you are interested in the security aspect, you may want to open a question over at [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AdminBee I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: @VictorChavauty to address your question re encryption, yes, encryption prevents direct modification of `/etc/shadow`, but other more sophisticated attacks are still possible with physical access. Look up “evil maid attacks” for more information, and then you’ll understand why many security professionals never leave their laptops unattended...

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you very much!

Comment: @StephenKitt, note that encryption isn't the same as authentication. There's a number of encryption methods that allow manipulating the plaintext with arbitrary bit flips (CTR and any stream ciphers, CBC partially). That allows for a lot if we can guess the plaintext. E.g. if `/etc/passwd` starts with `root:x:0:0...`, we could change that to `root::00:0...` by flipping some bits in just those two bytes. Of course, we'd need to find the file first, which isn't that easy if the whole filesystem is encrypted, but it's good to remember the distinction anyway.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, good point, confidentiality isn’t the same as integrity. `dm-integrity` provides the latter but its integration in `cryptsetup` & co is [still experimental](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#AUTHENTICATED_DISK_ENCRYPTION_(EXPERIMENTAL)).

Answer (score 3):

You can edit it directly, but making a wrong entry can cause damage to the OS, even making it inoperable which is why the program `vipw` (with -s flag) loads a temporary copy to make edits in and checks the syntax before saving and overwriting it.

Comment: "Damage to the OS" sounds rather drastic, doesn't it? What do you think will actually happen?

Comment: the worst scenario I am thinking of is making a syntax error in the sudo-user or root, being unable to authenticate. youd have to mount the drive externally and change the file (if you closed the shells / rebooted / power failure )

Comment: indeed. That shouldn't damage the OS itself (unless the program parsing the file is buggy), only causes difficulty for the user. And indeed that difficulty would also be rather minor if the user happens to have a working session live at the time.